# Improper downvotes from a user that I vote to close one of his questions

Tags: discussion, users, behavior

A few hours ago, I check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699873/convering-string-into-float-python-failed), which is not a proper question due to SO rules so I voted for closure with reason `Off-topic > Why isn't this code working` reason and downvote the question. Then I ask a question to clarify the question in the comments. In a few minutes, the question is closed. Then OP answer my comment-question and said he already state that in the question itself, but I reply with the information in the question is not sufficient to diagnose.

Then I realize 1-2 minutes after the closure of the question, I got 2 downvotes to 2 of my questions, and the reputation of the OP decreased a few. Then I asked the OP why he tries to punish me with downvotes because of an improper question he asked. I get no reply and in a few hours later I see that the question is deleted.

What is the best way to handle such a problem?

Comment: Ignore it? If they trigger the serial voting script it will be reversed, and maybe one or both votes is just a random coincidence, but either way I doubt there's much you can do that would improve the situation.

Comment: There's 13 seconds between the 2 downvotes. That's hardly a coincidence.

Comment: "_I got 2 downvotes to 2 of my questions, and the reputation of the OP decreased a few_"  Downvotes on questions are free, so the OP's rep drop is coincidental and not at all "proof" of their serial voting.

Comment: @Cerbrus So it's completely impossible for two different people to ever look at and vote on two different questions of this user within 13 seconds of each other?  No, sorry, but that's an entirely reasonable think to claim as coincidence.

Comment: @Servy: considering the amount of votes that user gets on a daily basis... Sure, it's _possible_, but extremely unlikely that those 2 votes came from different users.

Comment: Considering that four out of the five users who closed the question all got 2-3 downvotes in the same time frame (the 5th didn't, I assume, because they only had one question to be downvoted, and it was already negative), it's a strong likelihood that the OP *did* downvote you all, but that can't be *proven*.  And since you only got two downvotes, the serial voting script most likely *won't* reverse it, so, in short... the OP *may* have been a big baby about it, but there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I guess I am not clear in *I got 2 downvotes to 2 of my questions, and the reputation of the OP decreased a few*, I meant OP keep getting a few  more downvotes. Othervise, Question downvoting have no rep cost. Question closed and then 2 downvotes in a very short time.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables hit the nail on the head there. The OP was likely the user to downvote, but there's no way to be certain. (Aside from looking up his address and visiting him, which I would advise against). My guess is you got only 2 downvotes, because the OP is well aware of the serial voting script.

Comment: Speculating who downvoted you is silly, especially at this scale. What are you going to do, start a witch hunt because somebody meddled with a few imaginary internet points? It's completely possible that a real user saw an answer, looked at your profile, and downvoted a few poor questions/answers they found. It's also possible two completely unrelated users saw things they didn't like and downvoted. Trying to figure out whether the OP downvoted *two questions* is not terribly helpful.

Comment: The think that make me nervous is the behaviour, not reputation. I spent my free time to try to help and I try to act according to the general rules of SO. What I try to do is pushing the user to correct his question. A user with ~350 reputation probably know the way how people react in SO. But I was wrong I guess.

Comment: I'm afriad that this is fairly common.  On Jul 19,  I got two downvotes within 3 minutes on old, dead questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of the users that voted to close the question got downvoted at the same time.  Except one, the one that posted a helpful comment to the question.

We can hem and haw that there is no conclusive proof that it was the question's OP that did the downvoting. Or that the OP isn't using a sock account to do the voting even though it looks like he does.  I'm also not 100% certain that the Sun will rise tomorrow.

Clearly a moderator needs to be notified of this apparent mis-behavior.  I trust that your meta question will be sufficient.

Comment: I agree. Even though we can't be absolutely certain, it's "pretty unlikely" that all those downvotes came from random people.

Comment: Moderators don't care about issues like this; the standard line is, "Wait until the nightly processes trigger, and if it doesn't roll back, *and* it keeps happening, maybe notify us."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I guess it's time to find a question from that uswer we can cl... eh, nevermind ;-)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables my point is not punishing him. Just inform that (if he is the one who did this), what he had done is wrong. -4 rep is not problem for me. -4/~6000 rep is not important but what makes me uncomfortable is the way the user acts. If something is going to be done, then it should be for correcting the mis-behavior and warning the user about that.

Comment: In the scientific community, when an event happens at around a probability of 5 sigma or more, it's "strong enough" evidence. I'm not gonna try to estimate the probability of 4/5 close-voters getting downvotes in close time proximity to a closure. But mere dismissal as "mere chance" or "cannot be proved" is completely and absolutely absurd.

Comment: Turns out Stack Overflow is not a scientific community but an out-of-control social experiment...